# Python: Variable step length in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, range

I want to take step value in a for loop from an array. some thing like,

```
step = [0,1,2,15,3,87] #values in no order  
for i in range(0, len(raw_pkt), step):
```

The step value should be updated in each iteration. Is there any workaround for that? I know that `range()` expects an integer value not a list. But I want to take values from the list on each iteration.

Comment: No, in that case you better use a `while` loop. A `range(..)` is constructed once.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Requesting your dupe hammer services... ^

Comment: @DavidG I can't, I added the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Iterating through `step`:

If you think about what you are trying to achieve, you don't really care about the `list` that you are trying to `index` as the `step` values are *fixed*. So even if the length of the `raw_pkt` was a million, because your `step` list is only length `6`, you will only ever have `6` `indexes`.

Once you realise this, the code becomes pretty simple, you just want to `iterate` over the `step` values and increment a `variable`. This `variable` can be used to `index` a `list` or whatever, but this doesn't matter.

This makes the code pretty short and concise:

```
step = [0, 1, 2, 15, 3, 87]
i = 0
for s in step:
   i += s
   #code...
```

so to demonstrate that this works, we can do a more easy-to-follow example:

```
step = [0, 1, 2, 4, 1]
l = [5, 6, 3, 6, 2, 7, 3, 1, 8]
i = 0
for s in step:
   i += s
   print(i, l[i])
```

which `outputs`:

```
0 5
1 6
3 6
7 1
8 8
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want ist `itertools.accumulate`.

```
from itertools import accumulate

for i in accumulate([0,1,2,15,3,87]):
    print(i)

# would print 0 1 3 18 21 108
```

Comment: I don't think that was the question. i think the question was how to iterate over "raw_pkt" with steps defined in another list. - I might be wrong tho

Comment: @EvilSmurf I guess this is exactly what that question is about. The question only concerns the range creation, not the indexing of another array.

Answer (score 1):

```
step = [0,1,2,15,3,87] #values in no order for i in range(0, len(raw_pkt), step):

laststp = 0

for stp in step:
   for i in range(stp-laststp, len(raw_pkt), stp):
      #do something
      laststp = stp
      break #this should make sure that each step is applied once.
```

Comment: Have you forgotten to define `laststp` at the start of the `for-loop`? Because this won't run at the moment as `laststp` is not defined (as well as `raw_pkt` but I assume you are leaving that up to the OP)

Comment: Yes you're right

Answer (score 1):

there's an easy solution to this:

```
for pkt in [raw_pkt[i] for i in step]:
    print pkt
```

with

```
step = [0,1,2,15,3,87]
```

and

```
raw_pkt = [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199]
```

the result would be

```
100
101
102
115
103
187
```

Comment: Technically, this doesn't do what the OP wants, it seems as if they want the *`indexes`*, not the *`values`* from the `raw_pkt` `list`...

Comment: Also, you can change the `list-comprehension`:  `[raw_pkt[i] for i in step]` to a `generator` which is more *efficient*. i.e `(raw_pkt[i] for i in step)`.

Comment: the indexes are already in `step` - unless `step` contains values for which you want the index in `raw_pkt` in which case simply change the foor loop from `for pkt in [raw_pkt[i] for i in step]` to `for pkt_idx in [raw_pkt.index(i) for i in step]`

Comment: the way I understand the question, these are the `step` values *between* the `indexes`, so a normal `range` such as `for i in range(10)` would have a `step` `list` of `[1, 1, 1, ...]`

Comment: possible. that's where OP has to get more specific. if that is what (s)he wants, then I also agree with your answer.